# get the location details with in the range

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that i want to get the all location from one location to aother location.I know two locations latitude and longitude values.So how to get the all location details from first location to second location.

Comment: what kind of location you want between two location? Or you want to display line between this two location?

Comment: I want to get the list of resturents between two locations.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)getCordinate :(NSString *)strOrigin : (NSString*)strDestination
{
    NSMutableString *tempStrOrigin = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strOrigin];
    NSMutableString *tempStrDestination = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strDestination];

    //[tempStrOrigin replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NULL range:[NSMakeRange(0, [tempStrOrigin length])]];

    tempStrOrigin = [[tempStrOrigin stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"] mutableCopy];
    tempStrDestination = [[tempStrDestination stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"] mutableCopy];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false&mode=walking",tempStrOrigin,tempStrDestination];
    NSLog(@"URL:%@",url);

    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] delegate:self];
    if (urlConnection == nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pradeep Chakoriya" message:@"Connection Failed !" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Connection finish!!!");
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:responeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response in String:%@",str);

    SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:str];
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
    NSLog(@"Response Object:%@",jsonObject);

    NSLog(@"End location:%@",[jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"routes.legs.end_location"]);
    NSLog(@"Start location:%@",[jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"routes.legs.start_location.lat"]);
NSLog(@"Overview_polyline:%d",[[jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"routes.overview_polyline.points"] count]);
NSString *strTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"routes.overview_polyline.points"] objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"String Temp:%@",strTemp);

        NSLog(@"Decode points:%@",[[[self decodePolyLine:strTemp] objectAtIndex:0] class]);
}

-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine:(NSString *)encodedStr {
    NSMutableString *encoded = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:[encodedStr length]];
    NSLog(@"encoded:%@",encoded);
    [encoded appendString:encodedStr];
    NSLog(@"encoded:%@",encoded);
    /*[encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                                options:NSLiteralSearch
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];*/
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] autorelease];
        NSNumber *longitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] autorelease];
        //          printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
        //          printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *loc = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] autorelease];
        [array addObject:loc];
    }
    [encoded release];
    return array;
}

Use this code to get all latitute and longitute of origin to destination
```

Comment: result return in array of latitute and longitue of origin to destination

Answer (score 0):

its easy if you're using mongo you can use $nearSphere for mysql follow these tutorials

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Geo-Targetting-With-PHP-And-MySQL.html

all the tutorials are in mysql and php

Comment: im not a mobile app developer but the methods are same. You need to get a list of locations from a db or somewhere and find the lat,long values which are near the target value , and sort them in acceding order by lat and long.